# How do I put user input into an array of strings without a scanner in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, command-line

For an assignment, I have to create an array of names and the number of names and all of the names have to be on the command line. The number of names in theory is infinite. For example, java Electricity 2 Bob Alice

Presently my code looks like this:

```
int numResidents = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        String[] names = new String[numResidents];
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            names[i] = StdIn.readString(args[i + 1]);
        }
```

This is giving me an error saying "actual and formal argument lists differ in length", and I don't know what that means. I can't use a scanner despite most of the internet suggesting one because at the time this assignment was due, we did not work with scanners yet. How do I do this without one?

Comment: So you just want the array to contain `"Bob", "Alice"` and so on?  Then you don't need the `StdIn.readString` part.  Also, you probably want the `for` line to have `i < args.length - 1`.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I don't want it to specifically include "Bob, "Alice", that is just an example I chose. I need it to be able to take any number of names that I input and put them into the array

Comment: So, just copy them in.  No need to call `readString`.  You could do that in a loop, or use `System.arraycopy()`.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe change args[i + 1] to args[i]

```
int numResidents = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    String[] names = new String[numResidents];
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        names[i] = StdIn.readString(args[i]);
    }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `StdIn.readString`? Why not just assign the value of the argument directly into the array?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).